How to get permission to a specific folder in flutter
I am working on a WhatsApp Status app in Flutter. I was fetching the statuses from the .statuses directory using Manage External Storage permission because with Read External Storage Permission, I am unable to access that directory. But Google Play rejected my app because I was using Manage External Storage permission. Now I am looking for an alternative permission to access the WhatsApp's .statuses directory. In Other Status Saver Apps, I have seen the permission that says Use This Folder like in the below screenshot. Anyone, please guide me on how can I get this permission in Flutter?

We can get this kind of permission using saf (Storage Access Framework) and saf package is present on pub.dev
